# Estimating parameters on system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions, modeling

I am looking for some help estimating the parameters of a series of differential equations to assist fitting the experimental data I have collected.

**The Problem:**
The equations are based off of the work of fellow researchers:
[image: awesome equations]
(*PREDICTIONS OF CONCENTRATION IN THE PYROLYSIS OF BIOMASS MATERIALS--I V. K. SRIVASTAVA and R. K. JALAN, 1994*)

My fitting to my experimental data been pretty bad thus far using MATLAB.
[image: bad bad fit :(]
If you want my MATLAB code as well I would be happy to share. Reading around online leads me to believe this is mainly due to improper scaling of data in addition to *bad initial guesses*. Therefore, this is my attempt to better approximate the initial guesses for the parameters using Mathematicas manipulate function.

**My approach:**
I first started out defining constants and defining equation (6) from the research paper above. Rg is ideal gas constant ($kJ*mol^{-1}*K^{-1}$), HR is heating rate ($K*min^{-1}$), n are the reaction rates (n1=0,n2=n3=1.5 from literature), T is temperature ($K$).

```
Rg = 8.314*10^-3;
HR = 5; 
n1 = 0;
n2 = 1.5;
n3 = 1.5;
T = HR*t + T0;
```

I then defined the system of differential equations in the research paper above (1),(2),(3),(4) and the initial conditions (5) as so:

```
system = {
   Cb'[t] == -a1*exp (-e1/(Rg*T))*(Cb[t]^n1), 
   Cbp'[t] == 
    a1*exp (-e1/(Rg*T))*Cb[t]^n1 - a2*exp (-e2/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n2 - 
     a3*exp (-e3/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n3, 
   Cg'[t]  == a2*exp (-e2/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n2,
   Cc'[t]  == a3*exp (-g/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n3,
   Cb[0] == 1, Cbp[0] == 0, Cg[0] == 0, Cc[0] == 0
   };
```

Finally, I attempt to find the numerical solution to the set of ODE's by using Mathematicas ParametricNDSolve. I set the time interval to be from 0 --> 120 minutes, define my parameters and try to manipulate the equation parameters to find something close to resembling my data. I left the initial temperature (T0) as a parameter, though the reaction from experimental data began at around 325K. At a constant heating rate of 5K/min, the time at that point would be ~65 min into heating.

```
parfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   system, {Cb, Cbp, Cg, Cc}, {t, 0, 120}, {a1, e1, a2, e2, a3, e3,
     T0}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Through[parfun[a1, e1, a2, e2, a3, e3, T0][t]], {t, 0, 
   120}, PlotLegends -> {"Cb[t]", "Cb+[t]", "Cg[t]", "Cc[t]"}
  ],
 {{a1, 10}, 0.000001, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e1, 200}, 
  0.000001, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a2, 10}, 0.000001, 1000,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e2, 1}, 0.000001, 5000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a3, 10}, 0.000001, 1000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e3, 1}, 0.000001, 5000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{T0, 325}, 270, 1000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

My data is represented as Temperature in Kelvin in the first column and Equation (1) in the research paper for the second column.

```
data = {{328.284, 0.964936}, {333.399, 0.958594}, {338.515, 
  0.951508}, {343.63, 0.945054}, {348.745, 0.93767}, {353.86, 
  0.930621}, {358.975, 0.924241}, {364.091, 0.918532}, {369.206, 
  0.913828}, {374.321, 0.909571}, {379.436, 0.906699}, {384.552, 
  0.902843}, {389.667, 0.899256}, {394.356, 0.895557}, {399.897, 
  0.893198}, {405.013, 0.890616}, {410.128, 0.888927}, {415.243, 
  0.886568}, {420.358, 0.883986}, {425.473, 0.881068}, {430.589, 
  0.879044}, {435.704, 0.875904}, {440.819, 0.873992}, {445.934, 
  0.872079}, {451.05, 0.868269}, {456.165, 0.864346}, {461.28, 
  0.859754}, {466.395, 0.854045}, {471.511, 0.847107}, {476.626, 
  0.839836}, {481.741, 0.83232}, {486.856, 0.823817}, {491.545, 
  0.816521}, {495.808, 0.808806}, {499.644, 0.800254}, {503.054, 
  0.793412}, {506.465, 0.784241}, {509.875, 0.776555}, {512.859, 
  0.768897}, {515.842, 0.760681}, {518.826, 0.752716}, {521.81, 
  0.744918}, {524.794, 0.736366}, {527.778, 0.727981}, {531.188, 
  0.719429}, {534.598, 0.711211}, {538.008, 0.702269}, {541.419, 
  0.694721}, {544.829, 0.687876}, {548.665, 0.680476}, {551.649, 
  0.672473}, {555.205, 0.664087}, {557.069, 0.655255}, {561.027, 
  0.648548}, {564.863, 0.639606}, {568.274, 0.630329}, {570.831, 
  0.622772}, {573.815, 0.614992}, {576.799, 0.607214}, {579.868, 
  0.598194}, {582.426, 0.58951}, {584.642, 0.580256}, {587.456, 
  0.570534}, {589.928, 0.561144}, {592.656, 0.55343}, {595.129, 
  0.545915}, {598.539, 0.538331}, {601.949, 0.532287}, {605.785, 
  0.526689}, {610.474, 0.52098}, {615.589, 0.515829}, {620.705, 
  0.510343}, {625.82, 0.504746}, {630.935, 0.500154}, {636.05, 
  0.496231}, {641.166, 0.492197}, {646.281, 0.48794}, {651.396, 
  0.484241}, {656.511, 0.480095}, {661.627, 0.476285}, {666.742, 
  0.473032}, {671.857, 0.469446}, {676.972, 0.463736}, {682.087, 
  0.458808}, {686.947, 0.454328}, {692.318, 0.449735}, {697.433, 
  0.445366}, {702.548, 0.440997}, {707.664, 0.43607}, {712.779, 
  0.431478}, {717.894, 0.426662}, {723.009, 0.421958}, {728.124, 
  0.4177}, {733.24, 0.414785}, {738.355, 0.411864}, {743.47, 
  0.409951}, {747.875, 0.407258}, {754.553, 0.404675}, {759.668, 
  0.40254}, {764.784, 0.400404}, {769.899, 0.398715}, {775.014, 
  0.396133}, {780.129, 0.394891}, {785.245, 0.392644}, {790.36, 
  0.390173}, {795.475, 0.388038}, {800.59, 0.386461}, {805.705, 
  0.384437}, {810.821, 0.382748}, {815.936, 0.379831}, {821.051, 
  0.378923}, {826.166, 0.376788}, {831.282, 0.374541}, {836.397, 
  0.372293}, {841.512, 0.371051}, {846.627, 0.369251}, {851.743, 
  0.36812}, {856.858, 0.367102}, {861.973, 0.365189}, {867.088, 
  0.363054}, {872.203, 0.361253}, {877.319, 0.359229}, {882.434, 
  0.357094}, {887.549, 0.35574}, {892.664, 0.353046}, {897.78, 
  0.351246}, {902.895, 0.34911}, {908.01, 0.347399}, {913.125, 
  0.343313}, {918.24, 0.340358}, {923.441, 0.334761}, {928.471, 
  0.330393}, {933.586, 0.325219}};
pdata = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red}];
Show[pdata, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Temperature K], HoldForm[Concentration]}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

I keep getting issues trying to estimate the parameters. In particular:

```
Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`
```

I thought originally it was because the timestep was starting at zero in the numerical approximation, so I changed the times to start at 0.000001, as starting at t=0 would would lead to division by zero if the T0 was zero along with t, however this did not fix my issues.

I think my code requires a relatively simple fix, if someone who uses Mathematica frequently could take a look I don't think it would take too long to fix. Thank you!

Comment: The _Mathematica_ function for exponential is Exp\[\] (case sensitive) or simply E^().  You will want to replace "exp" appropriately.  I still had issues after the replacement.

Comment: Also, the activation energy for Cc'\[t\] equation is "g".  It probably should be "e3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected the typos leading to following *Mathematica* code:

```
Rg = 8.314*10^-3;
HR = 5;
n1 = 0;
n2 = 1.5;
n3 = 1.5;
T = HR*t + T0;
system = {Cb'[t] == -a1*E^(-e1/(Rg*T))*(Cb[t]^n1), 
   Cbp'[t] == 
    a1*E^ (-e1/(Rg*T))*Cb[t]^n1 - a2*E^ (-e2/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n2 - 
     a3*E^ (-e3/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n3, 
   Cg'[t] == a2*E^ (-e2/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n2, 
   Cc'[t] == a3*E^ (-e3/(Rg*T))*Cbp[t]^n3, Cb[0] == 1, Cbp[0] == 0, 
   Cg[0] == 0, Cc[0] == 0};
parfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   system, {Cb, Cbp, Cg, Cc}, {t, 0, 120}, {a1, e1, a2, e2, a3, e3, 
    T0}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@Through[parfun[a1, e1, a2, e2, a3, e3, T0][t]], {t, 0, 
   120}, PlotLegends -> {"Cb[t]", "Cb+[t]", "Cg[t]", "Cc[t]"}], {{a1, 
   8}, 0.000001, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e1, 40}, 0.000001, 
  100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a2, 294}, 0.000001, 500, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e2, 17}, 0.000001, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a3, 486}, 0.000001, 1000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e3, 32}, 0.000001, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{T0, 325}, 270, 1000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: TGA Plot]

There are problems with your reaction mechanism, because the zero order kinetics for Cb cause it to go negative.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much for taking the time to fix my mistakes! Seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @user3741793   You are welcome.  Good luck with your fits!